# Object.assign make duplicate when post a request

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, zendesk

I create a ticket using zendesk but I didn't know why this happens

here is node js code:

config.js

```
baseTicketObject: {
    'comment': {
      'body': null,
    },
    'requester': {
      'name': null,
      'email': null,
    },
    'custom_fields': [],
  },
```

create ticket api

```
function createTicketObjectFromRequest(req) {
  const requestBody = req.body;
  console.log('requestBody', requestBody);
  console.log('config.baseTicketObject', config.baseTicketObject);
  const ticket = Object.assign(config.baseTicketObject, {});
  //console.log('ticket', ticket);
  const {
    messageBody, email, name, customFields,
  } = requestBody;
  //console.log('ticket.custom_fields', ticket.custom_fields);

  // Request must contain a name, email and body
  ticket.requester.name = name;
  ticket.requester.email = email;
  ticket.comment.body = messageBody;

  if (req.user && req.user.id) {
    ticket.custom_fields.push(createCustomFieldObject(config.customFieldNameToZendeskFieldIdMapping['userId'], Number(req.user.id)));
  }
  Object.keys(config.customFieldNameToZendeskFieldIdMapping).forEach((fieldName) => {
    if (config.customFieldNameToZendeskFieldIdMapping[fieldName] === config.customFieldNameToZendeskFieldIdMapping.userId) {
      return;
    }

    //console.log('fieldName', fieldName);
    const mappedCustomFieldId = config.customFieldNameToZendeskFieldIdMapping[fieldName];
    if (mappedCustomFieldId) {
      ticket.custom_fields.push(createCustomFieldObject(mappedCustomFieldId, !customFields[fieldName] ? '' : customFields[fieldName]));
    }
  });

  return { ticket: ticket };
}
```

whenever I post a request the `config.baseTicketObject` will keep all items i pushed before like this

```
config.baseTicketObject { comment: { body: null },
  requester: { name: null, email: null },
  custom_fields: [] }
-------------------------------------
config.baseTicketObject { comment: { body: 'dgfhdgfhdgfh dgfhdfghdfg' },
  requester: { name: 'test other', email: 'tranthiphuonghue96@yopmail.com' },
  custom_fields:
   [ { id: 360010481051, value: '' },
     { id: 360010510411, value: '' },
     { id: 360010406792, value: '' },
     { id: 360010511011, value: '' },
     { id: 360010511191, value: '' },
     { id: 360010920852, value: 'contact_support' } ] }
---------------------------------------------------------
config.baseTicketObject { comment: { body: 'dgfhdgfhdgfh dgfhdfghdfg' },
  requester: { name: 'test other', email: 'tranthiphuonghue96@yopmail.com' },
  custom_fields:
   [ { id: 360010481051, value: '' },
     { id: 360010510411, value: '' },
     { id: 360010406792, value: '' },
     { id: 360010511011, value: '' },
     { id: 360010511191, value: '' },
     { id: 360010920852, value: 'contact_support' },
 { id: 360010481051, value: '' },
 { id: 360010510411, value: '' },
 { id: 360010406792, value: '' },
 { id: 360010511011, value: '' },
 { id: 360010511191, value: '' },
 { id: 360010920852, value: 'contact_support' } ] }
```

I don't know why the config.baseTicketObject like that, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse parameters order in `Object.assing`.

You have

`Object.assign(config.baseTicketObject, {});`

but should be

`Object.assign({}, config.baseTicketObject);`

**Object.assign syntax**

> Object.assign(target, ...sources)

In your case

```
const ticket = Object.assign({}, config.baseTicketObject);
```

**Edit:**

Add

`ticket.custom_fields = [];`

after

`const ticket = Object.assign({}, config.baseTicketObject);`

because `Object.assign` create [shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy), witch mean that `ticket.custom_fields` still holds reference to original array object from `config.baseTicketObject.custom_fields`

Comment: the config.baseTicketobject and ticket still Incremental, them are not refresh when i post a request

Comment: can you explain why this happen, i understand that can fix this problem but don't know why